# Getting a specific number of JSON items with jQuery from tumblr feed

Tags: jquery, json, tumblr

I'm trying to populate a page with X entries from my tumblr feed, and I'm wondering how I can only pull that X number from the JSON object it returns.

Here's my code, pulled from another Stack Overflow post and modified:

```
//Tumblr retrieval
$.getJSON("http://tumblr-address/api/read/json?callback=?", 
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.posts, function(i,posts){
      var title = this["regular-title"]; 
      var type = this.type; 
      var date = this.date; 
      var url = this["url-with-slug"];

      $('#sideRail ol').prepend('<li><p><a href=' +url +'>' + title + '</a></p><p>' + date + '</p></li>'); 
    });
 });
```

I've tried using a while loop with a counter, but it just repeats everything X times before moving on to the next item in the list.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Array.slice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) method on the post array. For example, to retrieve 10 items:

```
$.getJSON("http://tumblr-address/api/read/json?callback=?", 
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.posts.slice(0, 10), function(i,posts){
      // ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a terrible waste of bandwidth?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `num` query parameter:

```
$.getJSON("http://tumblr-address/api/read/json?num=20", ...
```

And I don't think you need to have a blank `callback` parameter. You're not doing JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

old post but updates info cant hurt...
yes the old api allowed the num= parameter to specify a l8imit to returned items, the new Api version 2 uses  'limit=' instead. but defaults to 20 if left out.